# Copying an array of characters to a string outside the function

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a function upperCase that takes a string and capitalises any characters without returning an extra string. Running the code below I get 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' when the memcpy command runs. Am I using memcpy incorrectly?

The commented out printArrChar just loops through the array and outputs its values, which outputs the intended letters from charArray.

```
void upperCase(const char *s){
    int i=0;
    size_t len = strlen(s)+1;
    char charArray[len];
    while (*(s+i) != '\0'){
        if (*s >=97 && *s <= 122){
            charArray[i] = *(s+i) -32;
        }
        else
        {
            charArray[i] = *(s+i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    charArray[len-1] = '\0';
    // printArrChar(charArray, sizeof(charArray)/sizeof(charArray[0]));
    memcpy(s, &charArray, len);
}
```

Edit: Full code for context. https://pastebin.com/Hf7HH5yu

I realise I made a mistake declaring my function as taking a const but giving it a non-constant array, but removing the const doesn't seem to fix the error.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: Passing a string literal?

Comment: Tip: Instead of *magical numbers* like 97, 122 and 32 just do `'a'`, `'z'` and `' '` respectively. It reads a lot better. Also instead of `*(s + i)` just do `s[i]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane In that case I would wonder where the OP expects to get the result in :) Oh, well, maybe they are passing a pointer to one.

Comment: why not just do the modif by changing s without `charArray` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the local array is copied back to the source.

Comment: If you're doing an in-place modification, just do an in-place modification. That temporary array doesn't help.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I meant if the usage is something like `upperCase("Hello")`

Comment: You declared `s` as a `const char *`. That is a promise that the function will not change the contents `s`. Yet the function uses `s` as the destination of a `memcpy`.

Comment: perhaps it should be `memcpy(s, charArray, len)`

Comment: Copying back into a `const char*` is asking for trouble.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I meant: `char *str = "Hello"; upperCase(str);` I can't follow your comments sorry.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's OK, nevermind.

Comment: Sorry I can't get your point at all. You can't modify a string literal, why are you taking issue with this?

Comment: If you want to uppercase the string _in-place_, you don't need `charArray`. But, you couldn't [shouldn't] use `const char *s` [you want: `char *s`] for that. If you want to pass back the uppercase string in a _different_ buffer, you want: `void upperCase(char *charArray,const char *s)` or [`char *charArray = malloc(strlen(s) + 1)`], you want `char *upperCase(const char *s)` and a `return charArray;` at the bottom.

Comment: Well, from your "full code" - `char *myString = "this is a string in c";` - this is defining a string *literal*, which is read-only. `myString` is just a pointer to that read-only memory.

Comment: You can fix the "full code" by declaring `myString` as an array, e.g. `char myString[] = "this is a string in c";` That will copy the characters of the string literal into an array that *can* be modified.